# How to send request to controller using mockmvs on junit with object parameter?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito, mockmvc

I am trying to send a request to a controller method and test it but I need to send a dto class as parameter. Here is the code:

```
 @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        saveUser();
    }

    @Test
    void saveUser() {
        UserDto userDto = new UserDto();
        userDto.setUsername("John");
        userDto.setEmail("john@foo.com");
        userDto.setPassword("password");

        this.mockMvc.perform(post("localhost:8080/registerUser")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(userDto)
                .andExpect....
    }
```

Here I need to send **userDto** as parameter but I could not, how can i send it and expect the result in **andExpect** block ?

Answer (score 0):

Map your entity to json and change `body` to `content`, like this:

```
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

this.mockMvc.perform(post("localhost:8080/registerUser")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(mapper.writeValueAsString(userDto))
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
```